# Uncorrect Bbox coordinates with get_window_extent() method and transform option

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, transform, renderer

I'm facing a strange issue here.

So my purpose is to draw a rectangle below one image and text wrapped around this image.
I then created a new axis and place the two strings on the top and right of it (using the `transform=ax_img.transAxes option)`.

Then I use the `r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()`  and `get_window_extent(renderer=r)` functions to get the coordinates of the image and the strings, and draw a rectangle with it.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

flash_pic = plt.imread("./statics/images/flash_decrease.png")

ax_img = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1], aspect='equal')
ax_img.imshow(flash_pic)

str_up = "This is"
str_right = "a random string"

text_up = ax_img.text(0, 1.1, str_up, fontsize=14, transform=ax_img.transAxes)
text_right = ax_img.text(1.1, 0, str_right, fontsize=14, transform=ax_img.transAxes)

r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

x0 = text_up.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).x0
x1 = text_right.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).x1
y0 = text_right.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).y0
y1 = text_up.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).y1

width = x1 - x0
height = y1 - y0
rect = ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x0, y0), width, height, transform=ax_img.transAxes, color='red'))

plt.show()
```

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXB9Z.png)

As you can see I am using again the image Axes to draw the rectangle but I also tried the "main" axes `ax` and it does not work either. I also tried other ways to place the text and images but this one is the most convenient to me. And Ithink it SHOULD work like !
So the thing is that the rectangle coordinates are incorrect, especially the right coordinate `x1`. It even changes the rendering if I am going full screen instead of reduced window.

I have seen little work around on this topic elsewhere so I was wondering if someone had a nice explanation / solution to fix this. I have tried several combinations to get the right coordinates or changing the transform = ... options but did not succeed.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXB9Z.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

matplotlib just makes a guess how big your font is,, and its a bad one until you draw.  So this is one of the rare cases where you should force a draw with `fig.canvas.draw` (soon to be `fig.draw_without_rendering()` in v3.5) before getting the extents:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

ax_img = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1], aspect='equal')
ax_img.imshow(np.random.randn(30, 30))

str_up = "This is"
str_right = "a random string"

text_up = ax_img.text(0, 1.1, str_up, fontsize=14, transform=ax_img.transAxes)
text_right = ax_img.text(1.1, 0, str_right, fontsize=14, transform=ax_img.transAxes)

r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

fig.canvas.draw()

x0 = text_up.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).x0
x1 = text_right.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).x1
y0 = text_right.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).y0
y1 = text_up.get_window_extent(renderer=r).transformed(ax_img.transAxes.inverted()).y1

width = x1 - x0
height = y1 - y0

rect = ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x0, y0), width, height, transform=ax_img.transAxes, color='red'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm in my real code, Thanks a lot !
I was suspecting that the artist selection was not right, but makes much more sens with the guessed font size :-)